# C# WPF Dynaically adding tabs byt loading xaml file clears radio buttons, why?

Tags: wpf, xaml, tabitem

So I have a window that contains a TabControl as the main UI element.  I add two tabs by default in the xaml editor.  When the program runs I want to add new tabs that have identical setups (but are different than the first two tabs).  I can do this by calling:

```
URLTabContentControl documentRoot = (URLTabContentControl)Application.LoadComponent(new Uri(@"URLTabContentControl.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Which loads up a control I have defined in a xaml file.  Basically this is what I want to show up inside of the new tab I will add. At this point I call:

```
TabItem ti = new TabItem();
ti.Header = "*New Capture URL " + (mainTabControl.Items.Count-1);
ti.Content = documentRoot;
int i = mainTabControl.Items.Add(ti);
mainTabControl.SelectedIndex = i;
```

Which creates the new TabItem adds a header and the control that was create via the xaml file.  The issue is the xaml file has several different radio button groups and everytime I add a new tab the radio buttons on the existing tabs all become unselected.  I don't think this is a bug in my code so I'm wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction.  None of the other types of controls have their state screwed up like this.

This is the xaml that becomes the content of the TabItems:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CustomCamApplication.URLTabContentControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="340" d:DesignWidth="634">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="45*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="42*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="41*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="31*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="34*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="29*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="118*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="101*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="105*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="65*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="45*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="30*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="88*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Content="URL Suffix:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,12,0,0" Name="urlSuffixLabel" VerticalAlignment="Top" ToolTip="Enter the part of the path that will be after the domain. http://my.domain.com:port/(enter this part)" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,14,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="401" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" />
    <Label Content="Video Source:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,10,0,0" Name="videoSourceLabel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" ToolTip="Select the video source you want to use for this URL." />
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,10,0,0" Name="videoSourceComboBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="401" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" SelectionChanged="videoSourceComboBox_SelectionChanged" />
    <Label Content="Captured Image" Grid.Row="2" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,10,0,0" Name="capturedImageLabel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="101" />
    <Label Content="Filename Prefix:" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,10,0,0" Name="filenamePrefixLabel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="95" ToolTip="Enter the front part of the file names used for capture file by this video source. Example prefix1002.png" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,12,0,0" Name="filenamePrefixTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Text="capture" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
    <Label Content="Capture Type:" Grid.Row="5" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="captureTypeLabel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="83" ToolTip="Store only a single image or store a series of images on the drive." />
    <RadioButton Content="Single Image" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,5,0,0" Name="captureTypeSingleRadioButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="captureType" IsChecked="True" />
    <RadioButton Content="Series" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,5,0,0" Name="captureTypeSeriesRadioButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="captureType" />
    <Label Content="File Format:" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,3,0,0" Name="captureFormatLabel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="73" ToolTip="Select the format of the stored capture files." />
    <RadioButton Content="PNG" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,8,0,0" Name="fileFormatPNGRadioButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="fileFormat" IsChecked="True" />
    <RadioButton Content="JPG" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,8,0,0" Name="fileFormatJPGRadioButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="fileFormat" />
    <RadioButton Content="BMP" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="3" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,8,0,0" Name="fileFormatBMPRadioButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="fileFormat" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
    <CheckBox Content="Zero Pad Image Series Names" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="2" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,15,0,0" Name="filenameZeroPadCheckBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" ToolTip="Example prefix00001.png" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
    <Label Content="Dimensions:" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,6,0,0" Name="captureDimensionsLabel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="73" />
    <RadioButton Content="Source Default" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="4" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,11,0,0" Name="captureDimensionsDefaultRadioButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="94" GroupName="captureDimensions" IsChecked="True" ToolTip="The default capture size for the selected video source." Checked="captureDimensionsDefaultRadioButton_Checked" />
    <Label Content="Capture Interval:" Grid.Row="6" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,5,0,0" Name="captureIntervalLabel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="101" ToolTip="Enter the number of seconds between frame captures." />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="6" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,7,0,0" Name="catureIntervalTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Text="5" PreviewTextInput="captureIntervalTextBox_PreviewTextInput"  DataObject.Pasting="captureIntervalTextBox_Pasting"/>
    <RadioButton Content="Reported Mode" Grid.Column="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="4" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,11,0,0" Name="captureDimensionsSourceReportedRadioButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="captureDimensions" ToolTip="Select a mode from one reported by the device." Checked="captureDimensionsSourceReportedRadioButton_Checked" />
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="4" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,6,0,0" Name="reportedModeComboBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="174" IsEnabled="False" />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you have 3 groups of radio buttons on your `URLTabContentControl` control titled Group1, Group2, and Group3. When you dynamically create a `TabItem` based on `URLTabContentControl` that instance then has yet another group of radio buttons that have since expanded on your initial group definitions. Those 3 groups are not isolated to each instance per se.

One way to test this theory is to leave a single grouping of radio buttons on your `URLTabContentControl` control and remove the group name and let the framework handle the default behavior; it should work as expected now since there is no explicit group name tied to the radio buttons on `URLTabContentControl`

Comment: Thanks a ton Aaron, I would never have thought of that. LOL.  I now dynamically set the radio button group names each time a new tab is loaded and that fixed the issue. I'd vote up on your answer but I'm new and don't have the rep points yet.